# how to fill a missing value with date and time stamp series in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which has aggregated data for some days. I want to  to fill a missing value with date and time stamp series in pandas

the data frame is
Case Number  createdDate             CS date                  EOL
90934987     9\2\2018 8:42:00 AM     7\9\2015 8:42:00 AM
79879879     7\8\2017 9:42:00 AM     8\5\2016 8:42:00 AM
56787889     3\6\2019 1:42:00 AM     5\9\2017 8:42:00 AM  6/12/2018 8:42:00AM
7845w767     9\3\2018 8:42:00 AM     8\7\2019 8:42:00 AM

I tried below code
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
f8 = pd.read_excel(r"")
f9=f8.fillna(0) 
f9.to_excel(r"")

expected output is :
Case Number  createdDate             CS date                  EOL
90934987     9\2\2018 8:42:00 AM     7\9\2015 8:42:00 AM   0\0\0000 0:00:00
79879879     7\8\2017 9:42:00 AM     8\5\2016 8:42:00 AM   0\0\0000 0:00:00
56787889     3\6\2019 1:42:00 AM     5\9\2017 8:42:00 AM  6/12/2018 8:42:00AM
7845w767     9\3\2018 8:42:00 AM     8\7\2019 8:42:00 AM  0\0\0000 0:00:00

but i got 
Case Number  createdDate             CS date                  EOL
90934987     9\2\2018 8:42:00 AM     7\9\2015 8:42:00 AM     0
79879879     7\8\2017 9:42:00 AM     8\5\2016 8:42:00 AM     0
56787889     3\6\2019 1:42:00 AM     5\9\2017 8:42:00 AM  6/12/2018 8:42:00AM
7845w767     9\3\2018 8:42:00 AM     8\7\2019 8:42:00 AM     0

Comment: `fillna(0)` fills integer `0`, so that is the output you see. There is no timestamp `0\0\0000 0:00:00` in pandas. You need to pick a valid timestamp to use as filled value. The smallest timestamp in pandas is `Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225')`. If you still want `'0\0\0000 0:00:00'` as filled value, you need to use it as `str`

Comment: but i am getting error NameError: name 'Timestamp' is not defined . i am subtarcating createad created and EOL date . so it is error TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Comment: but i am getting error NameError: name 'Timestamp' is not defined .

Comment: how to convert string to date formatt?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df.createdDate, format='%m\%d\%Y %I:%M:%S %p', errors
 ='coerce')`. Do this for each of your date column and assign it back. Change `/` and `\\` and the space between `second` and `AM/PM` part.

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
f8 = pd.read_excel(r".xlsx")
f9=f8.fillna('0/0/0000  0:00:00 AM') f10=pd.to_datetime(f9['Actual EOL Date'],format='%m\%d\%Y %I:%M:%S %p', errors ='coerce')  but still i am getting coulmn with empty rows